# Use content of a file as argument for program

Tags: perl, shell, arguments

I have a file A with content like this:

```
/filea
/fileb
/filec
/filed
```

And I have a script xyz.pl to read one file and do something with it

Now I want to provide each of the line in file A as argument to xyz.pl automatically. Effectively following commands are execute (in that order)

```
xyz.pl /filea
xyz.pl /fileb
xyz.pl /filec
xyz.pl /filed
```

Is there any quick one-liner-command to do that ?

Comment: Why not add some functionality to `xyz.pl` instead so you can pass a file name as argument, or receive arguments from STDIN?

Comment: It's not my program, so I don't want to mess with the code.

Comment: Are you forbidden from making a copy of the program and rewriting the input function?

Comment: I have reason not to do so. Of course you can open a black box to edit it, but what if other people are using it and you break some other parts of your system ?

Comment: I don't know your situation, so I can't really say what you should or should not do. If xargs does it for you, good for you. Me personally, I am a person who in all situations looks for the perfect solution, and in this case, the perfect solution is to alter the original script.

Comment: Thanks for trying, of course, that's your perfect solution, not mine though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use xargs with -n option

```
cat A | xargs -n 1 xyz.pl
```

Answer (score 4):

A one-liner in bash.

```
$ for f in `cat A`; do xyz.pl $f; done
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add a check for failure in there, aborting the loop if one of the iterations fails.

Comment: avoiding use of cat, and incorporating Donal's suggestion: `while read arg; do xyz.pl "$arg" || break; done < A`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs`. What that should do is take in each line of 'file A' (taken from `cat`) and execute the command given (`xyz.pl`) with that data as an argument.

```
cat 'file A' | xargs -I{} xyz.pl '{}'
```

That says that `{}` is where the argument should go, and puts it in after `xyz.pl`. It makes it more flexible in case you wanted to change the command in the future.

<del>Note, this solution as given will only work assuming each filename doesn't have spaces.</del>

**Edit:** Wait, it seems to work with spaces for me...

**Edit:** In case this doesn't work in all instances, here's an example:

**xyz.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Perl processing: $ARGV[0]\n";
```

**one.txt**

```
/filea
/fileb
/filec
```

**Running:**

```
$ cat one.txt | xargs -I{} ./xyz.pl '{}'
Perl processing: /filea
Perl processing: /fileb
Perl processing: /filec
```

Comment: this will not pass lines as args one by one

Comment: your code with I option will work, I had posted before you had edited I guess :P

Comment: thanks for trying... an up vote for more general cases, a bit complex for my case

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner would suffice:

```
perl -lnwe 'print qx(xyz.pl $_)' fileA.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-l`   -- autochomp each line, add newline to print (to avoid inconsistencies with newlines)
- `-n`   -- implicit `while(<>) { .. }` loop around program
- `qx()` -- execute command in shell and return standard output

Although the best option would no doubt be to alter your xyz.pl script to also accept arguments in the form of standard input. It is hard to say how you would do that, since I don't know how you process arguments. Then it would be a simple matter of:

```
perl xyz.pl < fileA.txt
```

Or with some options from e.g. [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong)

```
perl xyz.pl -f fileA.txt    # file as argument
perl xyz.pl /foo            # simple argument
```